# Cannot insert record to PostgreSQL in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ibm-cloud

I try to get postgresql work with Node.js in Bluemix platform. However, there is a problem. I tried to use the code described in https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/nodejs/index.html#PostgreSQL.

I can run the app I written successfully in local environment. However, it is not functioning properly in Bluemix platform.

Following is the code describing what I have done:

```
var recordVisit = function(req, res) {
    /* Connect to the DB and auth */
    pg.connect(psql, 
        function(err, client, done) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('Error requesting client', err);
            }

            console.log(req.ip);

            client.query('insert into ips(ip, ts) values($1, $2)', [req.ip, new Date()],
                function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        done();
                        return console.error('Error inserting ip', err);
                    }

                    client.query('select count(ip) as count from ips where ip=$1',
                        [req.ip], 
                        function(err, result) {
                            done();
                            if (err) {
                                return console.error('Error querying count', err);
                            }
                            console.log("You have visited " + result.rows[0].count + " times")
                            // res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                            // res.end();
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
    );
};
```

It is following the code from the bluemix document. The result of the visit count in Bluemix always be zero (0). But the result in local environment is okay. And I did not get any error from the Bluemix platform. So I assume that the visit record can be inserted. However, seems that it is not.

Can anyone have any pointer for me to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try taking the `where` out temporarily to make sure its inserting rows.

Comment: Check your logs, and add more logging statements.  For more info on logging in Bluemix, see the blog post ["Node.js debugging starts with better logging!"](https://ibm.biz/bluemix-logging)

Comment: Thanks for both, after doing more logging, I found that req.ip becomes undefined in the inner result function after INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to insert more logging into the insert function. I found that the variable req.ip becomes undefined in the result of INSERT SQL in Bluemix platform.

So I added a local variable to store the ip of the request in order to keep the content.